# jQuery for Chrome Packaged Application?

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I am completely new to writing chrome applications. What I'm trying to make right now is a simple flashcard application. How would I get jQuery to work in my packaged app? Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">

<head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#navbar').fadeOut(500);
        });
    </script>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>Add</li>
            <li>Edit</li>
            <li>My Stacks</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm just tring to fade out my navbar to test if jQuery works (it doesn't). I've tried to link to jQuery locally and from google, and neither work. I tried adding it with content_scripts in the manifest.json but when I reloaded the app it said content_scripts is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You cannot have inline scripts, you have to link to them externally.